# how to programmatically click button on another android app

Tags: android

I want to make an app to open another app and click on a coordinate.
I know it is possible in the windows app I'm just looking for a way for android.
I designed an app that opens another app.

+I'm the only user of my app, so it could have any permission that requires.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible that one android app sends clicks to another open android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569274/is-it-possible-that-one-android-app-sends-clicks-to-another-open-android-app)

Comment: No, it isn't. but it helps me

Answer (score 1):

I won't say it is impossible, probably with some hack, but it is impractical and raises a whole lot of issues. There are ways that Android allows for apps to share data and to communicate, but clicking button in another app, NO.

Comment: automation frameworks probably makes this possible, but i'm not sure

Comment: I want to make an app that opens another app and click on a coordinate why it is a hack?